# hola me sale este problema al querer usar node

Tags: nodejs, visual

PS C:\Users\Cesar Facundo\Desktop\se> npx create-next-app@latest
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Cesar Facundo\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Cesar Facundo\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.